# "BadValueError: Property category is required" on GAE

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to make a simple webapp html page that prints out data given from a datastore. However, I am continually running the following error:

```
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is required' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property category is required
```

I have heard that this is because I must initialize my properties beforehand but as of yet, have not found an appropriate way to do this.

The following is placed in model.py

```
class Question(db.Model):
  category = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  question = db.StringProperty(required=True, multiline=True)
  creator = db.StringProperty(required=True, multiline=True)
  answer = db.StringProperty(required=True, multiline=True)
  mustHave = db.StringProperty(required=False, multiline=True)
  group = db.StringProperty(required=False)
```

The following is given on a separate pages.py

```
class SpPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def printPage(self,path):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        template_values = getCommonValues(user)

        if user:
            template_values['questions'] = model.Question.all().fetch(100)
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
        else:
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'html/pleaseLogin.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

My html page is as follows:

```
Questions<br/>
{% for eachQ in questions %}
    <p>
    <a href='/doQuestionPage?id={{eachQ.key}}'>{{eachQ.question}}</a><br/>
    by {{eachQ.creator}}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The class to add data to datastore:
Note: this is attached to a form which posts data using this class. Not all code is in there so don't worry if some variables such as "something" don't appear to be used - they are. It seems to be working thus far.

```
class AddQuestion(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def doPost(self,something):        
    user = users.get_current_user()
    template_values = getCommonValues(user)

    c = self.request.get('cat')
    q = self.request.get('question')
    a = self.request.get('answer')
    m = self.request.get('musthaves')

    if user:
        emailStr = user.email().lower()
        if q and a and m:
            newQuestion = model.Question(category = c, question = q, creator = emailStr, answer = a, mustHave = m)
            newQuestion.put()
            template_values['message'] = 'New question created!'
```

Comment: Sean, how do the Question entities get into the database in the first place?

Comment: They are added through a separate page which has a form. This form POSTs to a separate class. I know that data is being put into the datastore since the forms are working and I can still retrieve the data through gets etc.
Here is a small tidbit of the code in the previously mentioned class:
c = self.request.get('cat')
q = self.request.get('question')
a = self.request.get('answer')
m = self.request.get('musthaves')
newQuestion = model.Question(category = c, question = q, creator = emailStr, answer = a, mustHave = m)
newQuestion.put()
template_values['message'] = 'New question created!'

Comment: Yes, I strongly suspect that there's a flow in the code that is storing the entities in the datastore because it makes absolutely no sense that you'd see this error otherwise when you are retrieving entities from the datastore.

Comment: If you look at the question entities in the datastore, do all of them have a value for the `category` property?

Comment: Yup! that was it! Found out that some objects did not have the category property! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some entities in your current datastore that don't have the category property, or other required properties, filled out. This could sometimes happen when you add the property to your model after already creating some other entities before that. Or perhaps adding the `required=True` option to a property that previously wasn't required.

If you are playing with dev data, I would suggest that you either clear your datastore or delete all your `Question` entities, and see if that works.

Otherwise, you'd have to manually add data to all the required fields or remove the `required=True` option.