# BadValueError('Property %s must be a float' % self.name) BadValueError: Property USD must be a float

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am having a problem with my Google App Engine Program.  I have been staring at it for a few hours now, and don't what the solution is.
I have seen another relevant question ["BadValueError: Property category is required" on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012476/badvalueerror-property-category-is-required-on-gae), but even when I remove the "required=True" condition from both the user and USD variables, I receive the same error.

My program does a simple conversion of USD currency to SR currency.
Unfortunately, I keep getting the error:
BadValueError('Property %s must be a float' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property USD must be a float

code from my main.py

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class Convert(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    USD = db.FloatProperty(required=True)
    SR = db.FloatProperty()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        conversion=db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Convert')
        values={'conversion':conversion}
        self.response.out.write(template.render('main.html',values))
    def post(self):
        prog= Convert(user=(self.request.get('userName')),USD=((float)self.request.get('currency'))),SR=((float)(self.request.get('currency')*3.75)))
        prog.put()
        self.redirect('/')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

code from my main.html

```
    <tr><td>{% for a in conversion%}
        <div align="right" lang="ar"><font size="+1" color="#000000"><strong><font color="#009999">{{a.user}}أدخل:</font>
        {{a.USD}}<font color="#990000">م</font> = {{a.SR}}{% endfor %}
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td>
        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <p align="right" dir="rtl"><strong><font color="#003366">أدخل الدولار الأمريكي:</font></strong><input type="text" name="currency" value="" id="currency"></input></p>
            <p align="right" dir="rtl"><strong><font color="#003366">الرجـاء إدخــال اسمـك:</font></strong><input type="text" name="userName" value="" id="userName"></input></p>
            <p align="right"><input type="submit" value="تحويل العملة"></input></p>
        </form>
    </td></tr>
```

Comment: This looks like it should be a syntax error, but can you try `float(self.request.get('currency'))` instead of `((float)self.request.get('currency')))`?

Comment: @Dan I tried that, still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The really odd part is, I renamed the USD, and SR variables to lowercase, and it worked. I don't know why it insisted the capital USD "Property USD must be a float", but when I changed them to lowercas usd and sr, it ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your error with the local server, instead I get:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...snip...
  File "/Users/user/helloworld/main.py", line 16
    prog= Convert(user=(self.request.get('userName')),USD=((float)self.request.get('currency'))),SR=((float)(self.request.get('currency')*3.75)))
```

The suggestion I make in the comments resolves both the syntax issue and your original issue (which I can only get if I remove the `(float)` statements):

```
def post(self):
  prog= Convert(user=self.request.get('userName'),USD=float(self.request.get('currency')),SR=float(self.request.get('currency'))*3.75)
  prog.put()
  self.redirect('/')
```